# How much pressure is needed to break an egg if applied from top and bottom?

Tags: pressure, home-experiment

Everybody knows that you can't break an egg with our fingers when pushing from top and bottom.

I assume if we could squeeze hard enough the egg would break?

Comment: Obviously yes. But if you want to know how much force you need, I suppose you just have to verify it experimentally, or at least know some experimental data about the hardness and shape of the egg.

Comment: humm in my mind if the forces were equal they would just cancel each other out.

Comment: They do, as long as the egg resists.
Imagine pulling a spring by the extremities. The forces cancel out in the sens that the spring doesn't globally move in one or the other direction, but this doesn't mean it stretches.

Answer (score -1):

233 atm, according to the following BBC link:
http://www.bbc.com/travel/story/20150415-the-quest-for-the-perfect-pad-thai

Comment: Link only answers are not a good idea. Resurrecting a two year old question -- that also is not a good idea.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Resurrecting 2 year old questions is, in general, perfectly fine (especially for previously unanswered ones!). In this case, the answer is given & the link is provided as reference (though I do not see the 233 atm cited anywhere in the text), so I think it's okay.

Comment: Resurrection is not only OK, but is encouraged by some badges. Doing so to answer an unanswered question is even better. Alas, this would appear to be the wrong link and the answer is very weak even if we get the right link.

Comment: More over somebody downvoted me :p

Comment: You could try (a) fixing the link and (b) fleshing out the answer. Otherwise I don't see why whoever did it would undo it nor why anyone else would come vote for this answer.